# Statistical analysis with very small sample size, 5 independent variables and 2 (possibly) dependent variables

Tags: regression, correlation, small-sample

I have a small sample size of 6 (they're conservation projects). They have been scored for 5 project design parameters (5 independent variables). And they have been scored for 2 desired project outcomes (2 [possibly] dependent variables).

What I want to know is do either of these two dependent variables correlate with any of the 5 independent variables - are they dependent? If so how strong are the correlations and can we compare?

With such a small sample size (6 projects) I really don't know what statistical analysis I'm supposed to run. I also don't know what statistical figures I should be paying attention to and comparing.

Answer (score 5):

I would

1. give up on hopes of finding strong evidence of anything.
2. avoid a null hypothesis statistical testing framework (i.e. don't trust any p-values).
3. do an exploratory analysis consisting of looking at lots of plots (to start with, every independent variable against each of the dependent variables) and simply calculating correlation coefficients (while ignoring the p-values).
4. if you want to be ambitious, you can write a Bayesian regression model and define priors for all the relationships, but it's probably not going to get you much more than an exploratory analysis in this case.

Comment: Abandon all hope, ye who seeks statistical significance with N=6. At traditional type I/II error rates, the correlation coefficient would have to exceed 0.97 before it becomes significantly different from 0.

Comment: @NuclearWang And even worse, if you find significant results, they are surprisingly likely to be in the wrong direction. Andrew Gelman calls this a 'Type S' (for 'sign') error, as opposed to a 'Type M' (magnitude) error.